# TextView not displaying Characters like "à è ì ò ù" in android

Tags: android, character-encoding, textview

TextView not displaying Characters like "à è ì ò ù" in android.
How can i encode/decode String to solve this problem in android ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your text contains html tags then you can try this :

```
textView.setText( Html.fromHtml ( textData ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

we can handle this issue and its depreciation in this way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
            Spanned result;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
            } else {
                result = Html.fromHtml(html);
            }
            return result;
        }
```